# Symfony2 starting and killing background process

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony command that need to run on the background since its a long running task. I already search on google for how many hours but I couldnt find an answer. Let's say I have this new process in symfony.

```
    $process = new Process('php app/console run:task:import');
    $process->start();
    return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($process->getPid());
```

As stated on the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously). Any asynchronous process can be stopped at any time with the stop() method;

```
$process->stop(timeout, signal);
```

now what if I have two process? import1 and import2. How can I stop only import2?

Comment: `import2->stop()`?

Comment: Well @u_mulder you have the point. I will try that. Thanks